# Why my result does not show

Tags: android, activity-recognition

My code does not show the result from activity recognization service. 
How can I solve my problem?

This is my code ActivityRecognizeService.java

```
package com.kobe.internship.realtimeactivity;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.DetectedActivity;

import java.util.List;

public class ActivityRecognizedService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "ActivityRecognizedServi";
    public ActivityRecognizedService(){
        super("ActivityRecognizedService");
    }

    public ActivityRecognizedService(String name){
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        if(ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent)){
            ActivityRecognitionResult result = ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent);
            handleDetectedActivity(result.getProbableActivities());
        }
    }

    private void handleDetectedActivity(List<DetectedActivity> probableActivities){

        for (DetectedActivity activity: probableActivities) {
            switch (activity.getType()) {
                case DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE: {
                    Log.d(TAG, "handleDetectedActivity: IN_VEHICLE: " +activity.getConfidence());
                    break;
                }
                case DetectedActivity.ON_BICYCLE: {
                    Log.d(TAG, "handleDetectedActivity: ON_BYCYCLE: " + activity.getConfidence());
                    break;
                }
                case DetectedActivity.ON_FOOT: {
                    Log.d(TAG, "handleDetectedActivity: ON_FOOT: " + activity.getConfidence());
                    break;
                }
                case DetectedActivity.RUNNING: {
                    Log.d(TAG, "handleDetectedActivity: RUNNING: " + activity.getConfidence());
                    break;
                }
                case DetectedActivity.STILL: {
                    Log.d(TAG, "handleDetectedActivity: STILL: "+ activity.getConfidence());
                    break;
                }
                case DetectedActivity.WALKING: {
                    Log.d(TAG, "handleDetectedActivity: WALKING: " + activity.getConfidence());
                    break;
                }
                case DetectedActivity.TILTING: {
                    Log.d(TAG, "handleDetectedActivity: TILING: " + activity.getConfidence());
                    break;
                }
                case DetectedActivity.UNKNOWN: {
                    Log.d(TAG, "handleDetectedActivity: UNKNOWN: " + activity.getConfidence());
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.kobe.internship.realtimeactivity;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognition;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    public  GoogleApiClient mApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .addApi(ActivityRecognition.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(MainActivity.this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(MainActivity.this)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityRecognizedService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.requestActivityUpdates(mApiClient, 2000, pendingIntent);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

AndroidMainifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kobe.internship.realtimeactivity">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".ActivityRecognizedService"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle(Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kobe.internship.realtimeactivity"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**My result**
[image]

It does not show the activity 
It could show the activity like below 
[image]

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: I don't understand why my result does not show like a white result. (the white is the result that I crop from the tutorial that I follow.

Comment: You should use `ActivityRecognitionClient` instead of `GoogleApiClient`. refer this [file](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/ActivityRecognition/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/activityrecognition/MainActivity.java) from official `Activity Recognization` GitHub repo